# Will SQL Alias compromise existing connections to [cluster name]/[database name]?

Tags: sql-server, alias

On a migration project we plan to use SQL Alias, since we learned it should be easier to use when moving databases between servers. The plan forward is to continue to move around databases to other servers at least two times more.

Since we’re moving from one cluster to another, I’m worried that we compromise existing database connections that don’t use alias.

**Will SQL Alias compromise existing connections to [cluster name]/[database name]?**

Comment: No, since the alias is only put on the client machines that need it.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Thanks! I just learnt it too :-) Put it as an answer, and I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't interfere. The alias is only needed on the servers or clients that will require the updated address. It can work in conjunction with any other names or addresses available without issue.